# More Publish/deploy exe from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I got my app successfully published, ran the setup.exe just fine, but it lloks like the app was installed in an odd place, buried way down deep:

C:\Users\sndevfarmsvc\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\HQ0721DB.Z4Q\8TDK6PMR.A39

Is this normal?  In the publish section of the project in VS 2010 there is a place for installation folder, but that requires a URL....what if I want it always to install to c:\program files\ on whatever machine it is run on?

thanks,

Phil J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's normal for a ClickOnce application.

The installation folder is the location where there application is installed **from**.

If you want to install into a different location you'll have to use a different installation program.